# Comparing two graphs in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, similarity

I am new to Neo4j and I am trying to compare two graphs in Neo4j. My first question is how to create two different graphs on Neo4j. I created something like below which is just like two disconnected graphs.

[Neo4j graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Org22.png)

Is this the best way we can have two graphs in Neo4j for comparison or there is another way?

My second question is based on my requirement to find the common vertices and common edges in both graphs. How to get this information? I am using Java to connect to Neo4j to create and run Cypher queries.

There are some questions asked on this platform about this but none seems to be quite what I am looking for.
If anyone can even suggest better ways to implement similarity algorithms on large graphs, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the standard Neo4j browser, you can only have a single Network view. You could use the concept of "virtual nodes", or use styling features that allow you to detect the differences visually. Perhaps this https://youtu.be/7iMraBHtTqE inspires you.

Disclaimer : I am the owner of Graphileon.